# Django db field not displaying modified slug field value after serializing

Tags: django, field, slug, json-serialization

I am trying get the user names instead of user id, in the created_by field of the Comment class. My model is below:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    thread_id = models.ForeignKey(Thread, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content = models.TextField()
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Have used slugfield in the serializer.

```
class CommentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    created_by = serializers.SlugRelatedField( 
                        slug_field='email',
                        queryset=User.objects.all())
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ("id", "thread_id", "content", "created_by", "created_at", "likes")
```

Where as in the api below, the field created_by still has user id and not email.

```
 @action(detail=True, methods=["GET"])
    def list_comments(self, request, pk):
        comments = Comment.objects.filter(
            thread_id = pk
        )
        data = json.loads(serialize('json', comments))
        print("**************data**************")
        print(data)
        return Response(data, status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

The data printed looks like this :

```
[{'model': 'blog.comment', 'pk': 20, 'fields': {'thread_id': 19, 'content': 'hi', 'created_by': 2, 'created_at': '2021-07-14T03:34:11.333Z', 'likes': 0}}]
```

Is this because of serialize? How do I correctly get the value of the created_by as user email and not id ?

Answer (score 0):

Use to_representation() method on the serializer

```
def to_representation(self, instance):
    rep = super(CommentSerializer, self).to_representation(instance)
    rep['created_by'] = instance.created_by.email
    return rep
```

Comment: Thank you for this. This works when I call the in-built API. When I hit this url ( inbuilt API ) :  http://0.0.0.0:8004/blog/api/comment/  , below is the created_by field data which appears as expected.
```{
        "id": 19,
        "content": "comment content",
        "created_at": "2021-07-14T03:13:31.284656Z",
        "likes": 0,
        "thread_id": 20,
        "created_by": "abc@gmail.com"
    }
```

Comment: Where as when I hit the url(http://0.0.0.0:8004/blog/api/comment/19/list_comments/)  of the custom API I have written, which is below:
```{
action(detail=True, methods=["GET"])
    def list_comments(self, request, pk):
        comments = Comment.objects.filter(
            thread_id = pk
        )
        for comment in comments:
            print(comment.created_by)
        data = json.loads(serialize('json', comments))
        print(data)
        return Response(data, status.HTTP_200_OK)
}```
The created_by field still carries the id :
"created_by": 5

Comment: You are not using your serializer in the custom action,
try:         'serializer = CommentSerializer(comments, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)'

Comment: thank you. This works. The data after filtering shows the created_by field appropriately. But to send to the frontend, I'm converting to json using this : data = json.loads(serialize('json', comments))
This is again getting back the id in the created_by field

Comment: You are getting id's because you are serializing data straight from the db instead of using a serializer. If you don't want to use a serializer, convert your queryset to a dict and iterate through it changing values in the dict, then serialize. Serializers were made exactly for that purpose, use a serializer like in the comment above.